# History of the correspondence between nouns and verbs

Tags: grammar, prepositions, history

Have English verbs been used always in plural form for plural nouns or is there a history to this correspondence?

Comment: You mean the regular verb conjugation, e.g. to ask becomes he ask**s**? It's not a "plural form" of the verb...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, English has often marked plural verbs to agree with plural subjects, as well as tenses like present and past, moods like the subjunctive and the indicative (in Old English), and agreement with first, second, and third person, too. All in one suffix, with an occasional prefix or vowel change.

Nowadays English verbs only have one agreement marker -- final -S in third person singular
(*I run, She run**s***). But in Old English, **everything** got marked on the verb.

A sample Old English paradigm:

***Singan*** - "to sing"  (Modern English forms: *sing, sings, singing, sang, sung*)

Infinitives *singan, tō singenne*
Present participle  *singende*
Past participle *(ġe)sungen*

Present indicative

- *iċ singe* 'I sing'
- *þū singst* 'You (sg) sing'
- *hē/hit/hēo singþ* 'He/It/She sings'
- *wē/ġē/hīe  singaþ* 'We/You (pl)/They sing'

Imperative

- Singular *sing*!
- Plural  *singaþ*!

Present subjunctive

- *iċ/þū/hē/hit/hēo singe*
- *wē/ġē/hīe  singen*

Past indicative

- *iċ  sang*
- *þū  sunge*
- *hē/hit/hēo  sang*
- *wē/ġē/hīe   sungon*

Past subjunctive

- *iċ/þū/hē/hit/hēo    sunge*
- *wē/ġē/hīe   sungen*

---

This is very much like Modern Standard German, which still has most of the inflections,
in maddeningly similar-but-not-quite-the-same paradigms:

***Singen*** "to sing"

Infinitive  *singen* 
Present participle  *singend*
Past participle *(ġe)sungen*

Present indicative

- *ich    singe* 'I sing'
- *du singst* 'You (sg) sing'
- *er/es/sie  singt* 'He/It/She sings'
- *wir singen* 'We/sing'
- *ihr singt* 'You (pl) sing'
- *sie singen* 'They sing'

Imperative

- Singular *sing*!

Past indicative

- *ich sang*
- *du sangst*
- *er sang*
- *wir sangen*
- *ihr sangt*
- *sie sangen*

Present subjunctive

- *ich singe*
- *du singest*
- *er singe*
- *wir singen*
- *ihr singet*
- *sie singen*

Past subjunctive

- *ich sänge*
- *du sängest*
- *er sänge*
- *wir sängen*
- *ihr sänget*
- *sie sängen*

As one can see, the languages are related; but English has lost almost all of these forms.

Comment: Even I can't remember that far back.